# Why isn't my node setup working to create a smoke effect in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I looked up how to do smoke in cycles, and ended up [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/volume.html). Following their setup, I ended up with a completely transparent object. I tried to apply the material to a cube, and placed a Suzanne head (with no material applied) behind it to better see the effect. I have attached images of the scene in solid view and rendered view, as well as an image of my material nodes. If other screenshots or info are needed, just ask.
[image: Solid View]

Comment: I don't see a screenshot of rendered view...[please post your blend here.](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: Did you setup/run a smoke simulation?

Comment: The setup shown in that link only creates a material for smoke. To have actual smoke, you need to have an object emitting the smoke inside the cube, and run a [smoke simulation](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/physics/smoke/).

Comment: Thanks pycoder and Duane Dibbley. I feel pretty foolish for not researching enough before asking the question.

Comment: @FoitGuy That's alright, just consider it a lesson learned for future Q's ;-)

Comment: In no way do I think you're foolish. You obviously found the link that you included in your question, so you must have done some searching before coming here, and nowhere on that page does it say that you need to run a simulation to get the smoke to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I'm a fool. Thanks to pycoder for pointing out my error. I forgot to add the Quick Smoke Simulation. It seems to work now. I have lots of smoke! Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31245)

Comment: I his defense, I didn't actually leave an answer, and this sort of answers the question anyway :-)

Comment: But note that @ShadyPuck's comment is a canned response put there by the review system, so don't worry about it *too* much :)